# Store lambda in a variable in kotlin

Tags: android, lambda, kotlin

I'm starting developing in Android with kotlin and I have a problem with lambdas. I have a function to set a listener in my view, this looks like this:

```
fun setListener(listener: () -> Unit) {
}
```

The problem is that the code passed as lambda won't be executed in setListener function, it will be executed in another part of my code (specifically when an item of a spinner is selected) so I have to "save" or "store" this lambda into a variable/property so that I'm able to execute it when needed. Any idea about how to do it?

Edit: I've achieved it by doing:

```
private var listener: (() -> Unit)? = null

fun setListener(listener: () -> Unit) {
    this.listener = listener
}
```

Is there a better way to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 24):

Here's how you can do it:

```
class Foo {
    private var listener: () -> Unit = {}
    fun setListener(listener: () -> Unit) {
        this.listener = listener
    }
}
```

However, manually writing setters is discouraged in Kotlin. Instead, you can just make your property public:

```
class Foo {
    var listener: () -> Unit = {}
}
```

For reference, here are the [docs about properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html) with lots of examples.

Comment: "Getter visibility must be the same as property visibility" (i.e. you cannot have `public set` with `private get`). I suggest `var listener: () -> Unit = {}`.

Answer (score 14):

You can store a function in a property easily. The simplest way:

```
var listener: (() -> Unit)? = null
```

Usage:

```
foo.listener = { println("called") }
```

If you want your property to be set-only, you can create one public property with unusable getter and one private property for internal use. Full example:

```
class Example {

    // for internal use
    private var _listener: (() -> Unit)? = null

    // public set-only
    var listener: (() -> Unit)?
        @Deprecated(message = "set-only", level = DeprecationLevel.ERROR)
        get() = throw AssertionError() // unusable getter
        set(value) { _listener = value } // write-through setter

    fun somethingHappend() {
        _listener?.invoke()
    }
}
```

Comment: With this code I get an error also when trying to use _listener inside my class

Comment: @aloj I've augumented & clarified my answer. If you're still getting error, post error message.

Comment: You could just make the getter private with `private get() = ...`. Then you don't even need the `_listener` property.

Comment: @diesieben07 you can't set setter vilibility lower than getter visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example.

```
fun main(){
    val result=::sum //function assign to variable (first method)
    val result1: (first: Int, second: Int) -> Int=::sum //function assign to variable (second method)
    print(result(5,6))

}
fun  sum(first:Int,second:Int):Int{
    return first+second;
}
```

Comment: This answer should be marked as correct solution : the =:: is the key