# What does ".()" mean in Kotlin?

Tags: android, object, kotlin, navigation-drawer, higher-order-functions

I've seen examples where a function has an argument given by ClassName.()
This doesn't seem to be an extension function, which is ClassName.Function()

An example is [Kotterknife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/kotterknife/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/kotterknife/ButterKnife.kt#L82):

```
private val View.viewFinder: View.(Int) -> View?
    get() = { findViewById(it) }
```

Which I don't quite know the function of,

and [MaterialDrawerKt](https://github.com/zsmb13/MaterialDrawerKt/blob/master/library/src/main/java/co/zsmb/materialdrawerkt/builders/DrawerBuilderKt.kt#L26)

```
fun Activity.drawer(setup: DrawerBuilderKt.() -> Unit = {}): Drawer {
    val builder = DrawerBuilderKt(this)
    builder.setup()
    return builder.build()
}
```

Where the code allows you to directly call

```
drawer {
    ...
}
```

rather than give it arguments surrounded by the parentheses.

Is there any documentation on this anywhere?

Comment: You should take a look on lambdas with receivers: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver

Comment: And if the last parameter of a function is a lambda, you can pull it out of the parenthesis and into a block surrounded by { }, as in your `drawer` example

Answer (score 65, accepted):

A function that takes in nothing and returns nothing in Kotlin looks like:

```kotlin
var function : () -> Unit
```

The difference is that the function in your code takes in nothing, returns nothing, **but is invoked on an object**.

For example,

```kotlin
class Builder (val multiplier: Int) {
    
    fun invokeStuff(action: (Builder.() -> Unit)) {
        this.action()
    }
    
    fun multiply(value: Int) : Int {
        return value * multiplier
    }
}
```

The important bit here is the way we've declared the type of `action`

```kotlin
action: (Builder.() -> Unit)
```

This is a function that returns nothing, takes in nothing but **is invoked on an object of type `Builder`**.

This means when we use this builder like so

```kotlin
var builder = Builder(10)
builder.invokeStuff({
    var result = multiply(1)
    println(result)
})
```

The context of `this` has been set to the builder object and we can invoke functions declared within the builder.

**[Refer more here](http://codeofrob.com/entries/looking-at-kotlin---fun-with-functions.html)**.

Answer (score 32):

this is a good question. so when you have this kind of statement:  `T.()`

it means that in the lamda you will be passing in, "this"  (which is the current object) will be of type T. Lets take a look how easy it its to understand:

Lets say we have some class with a function called myFun which takes in a lambda defined like this:

```
 class MyObject {
        fun myFun(doSomething: MyObject.()->Unit) {
            doSomething()
        }

        fun doAnotherThing() {
            Timber.d("myapp", "doing another thing")
        }
    }
```

to call this function i'd do this:

```
MyObject().myFun { doAnotherThing() }
```

see how it knew to use the MyObject() reference as the "this". this is really calling this.doAnotherThing() where this is the Myobject() instance just created.

could have also done this:

```
MyObject().apply{myFun { doAnotherThing() }}
```

Comment: Hi, why you call it using doAnotherThing()  all the times? how is doAnotherThing() related here? I dont understand it

Comment: im just demonstrating that the reference does not need to use this.doAnotherThing() simply doAnotherThing()

Comment: This answer is actually more helpful

Comment: But why can you still call basically any function in myFun block? E.g MyObject().myFun { functionNotDeclaredInMyObject() }

Answer (score 8):

There is a misunderstanding that T.() -> Y is  (T.()) -> Y, but actually is T.(()->Y).
As we know (X)->Y is a lambda, so T.(X)->Y is an extension on T.

If there is no parameter, the form is
T.() -> Y

It's interesting that we can call it in two ways as the blew.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*


open class MyClass(var name: String){
    open fun something(){println("myclass something")}
}


fun main() = runBlocking{
    val me = MyClass("Boll")
    val someMethod: MyClass.(Int) -> String = { n ->
        List(n){"X"}.joinToString(separator="", postfix=":${this.name}")
    }
    val some = me.someMethod(10)
    //val some = someMethod(me, 10)
    println(some)

    val anotherMehtod: MyClass.() -> String = { 
        "Y:"+this.name
    }
    //val another = me.anotherMehtod()
    val another = anotherMehtod(me) 
    println(another)
}
```

Comment: That's really interesting finding. I'm quite curious how anotherMehtod(me) works.

Answer (score 5):

Answer of @Kris Roofe make the things clear. Let me add more to it.

> **fun Activity.drawer** means that we are making an extension function name `drawer` in `Activity` class. That's the reason we can call
>   drawer method directly from an Activity class or child of an Activity
>   class.

More on extension functions [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html).

> **(setup: DrawerBuilderKt.() -> Unit = {})** In this statement we can see the power of kotlin higher order functions. Small intro of Higher
>   order functions :- `It is a function that takes functions as parameters, or returns a function.` So here **setup** param is a
>   function which return Nothing or **Unit**(Same as Void in java).
>   **DrawerBuilderKt.()** means that the function can be invoked using object of `DrawerBuilderKt` class. **= {}** means that **setup** parameter is
>   optional. So the function takes no parameters and return nothing.

More on Higher order functions [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html) and [here](https://medium.com/@agrawalsuneet/higher-order-functions-in-kotlin-3d633a86f3d7). More on optional parameter [here](http://blog.jimbaca.com/optional-params-in-kotlin/).

> **private val View.viewFinder: View.(Int) -> View?** it store a function in a property. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43811599/store-lambda-in-a-variable-in-kotlin) more info about the same. Rest of the things are same as explained above.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

"T.()" this  a extension function as parameter

```
class Human {
    fun eat() {
        println("only eat")
    }
}

fun Human.sleep(){
    println("krok")
}

fun whatHumanCanDo(test:Human.() -> Unit) {
    val human = Human();
    human.test()
    human.sleep()
}

fun main() {
  
  whatHumanCanDo {
      println("help")
      println("each")
      println("other")
      println("and")
      println("respect")
  }

    val badHuman = Human()
    badHuman.eat()
    badHuman.sleep()
    //badHuman.test() //not recognized
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is documentation on this. The concept is called "function literals with reciever" and is described here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver.

In essence, the lambda has access to the receiving object's members and can refer to the object with `this`. As mentioned previously, it's basically a lambda as an extension function.