# is it possible to assert on a function with parameter of type function of no parameters and no result?

Tags: kotlin, mockito

I am trying to figure out the following:

I have a mocked method, inside this mocked class there is a function with parameter of a function that takes nothing and void return, something like this [What does ".()" mean in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44427382/what-does-mean-in-kotlin)

```
fun invokeStuff(values: (MyParametersBuilder.() -> Unit)) {
        // do something and extract values
    }
```

`MyParametersBuilder` class has some setters for its own properties.

so when I invoke it I do this

```
MyClass().invokeStuff{
     setEnableFlagA(true)
}
```

So now using `Mockito` I came to this problem where I cannot mock the result of invokeStuff since I have no idea how to do it or if its even possible.

Basically, I cannot do this:

```
when(myClass.invokeStuff(any(MyParametersBuilder)).thenReturn... <- it says this method doesn't exist
```

neither

```
when(myClass.invokeStuff{any(Boolean::class.java)}.thenReturn... <- compiles but doesnt match anything
```

nor

```
when(myClass.invokeStuff{}.thenReturn... <- doesn't match either
```

Any idea how could I do this? Im using kotlin and mockito.

Comment: Try to use mockito doNothing or doAnswer methods https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-void-methods

Comment: both doAnswer and when... return work the same in this scenario, but thanks