# Which kotlin language feature is this

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-dsl

I'm learning about the kotlin DSL, specifically with Teamcity and I see an initialization pattern I don't really understand yet

[Kotlin playgound link](https://pl.kotl.in/bT4gUckuw)

Here is the code

```
package org.arhan.kotlin

fun main() {
    val project = project {
        configuration {
            step {
                name = "step 1"
                command = "hi"
            }
            
            customstep {
                name = "flang"
                anotherCommand = "derp"
                command = "1111"
            }
        }
    }
    println(project.configurations[0].steps[1].command)
}

fun project(block: Project.() -> Unit): Project {
    return Project().apply(block)
}

fun Project.configuration(block: Configuration.() -> Unit): Configuration {
    val configuration = Configuration().apply(block)
    configurations.add(configuration)
    return configuration
}

fun Configuration.step(block: Step.() -> Unit): Step {
    val step = Step().apply(block)
    steps.add(step)
    return step
}

class Project {
    var configurations = mutableListOf<Configuration>()

    fun build(block: Configuration.() -> Unit) = Configuration().apply(block)
}

class Configuration {
    var steps = mutableListOf<Step>()
}
 
open class Step {
     final lateinit var name: String 
     var command: String = ""
}

open class CustomStep(): Step(){
    var anotherCommand: String = ""
    constructor(init: CustomStep.() -> Unit): this(){
        // what does this do?
        init()
    }
}

fun Configuration.customstep(block: CustomStep.() -> Unit): Step {
    // how is this constructor initialized
    val step = CustomStep(block)
    steps.add(step)
    return step
}
```

Specifically the question is about how the `CustomStep` class is initialized. It take's in a lambda with `CustomStep` [as the reciever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44427382/what-does-mean-in-kotlin) (is this the correct terminology?).

And then I call `init()` in the constructor, which initializes the newly created `CustomStep` based on the block that was passed in.

I'm not sure how that initialization works. Or rather, which specific Kotlin language feature is being used here.

And how is this different if instead I wrote it the following way?

```
open class CustomStep(): Step(){
    var anotherCommand: String = ""
    // no constructor
}

fun Configuration.customstep(block: CustomStep.() -> Unit): Step {
    // use apply vs. passing in the block
    val step = CustomStep().apply(block)
    steps.add(step)
    return step
}
```

Thank you

Comment: I believe that's an implementation of a [type-safe builder](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/type-safe-builders.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `init()` is referring to the parameter `init: CustomStep.() -> Unit`:

```
constructor(init: CustomStep.() -> Unit): this(){
//  vvvv    ^^^^
    init()
}
```

You are simply calling what you passed in, on `this`. `init` needs a `CustomStep` as receiver after all. As with most situations when calling something on `this`, `this` can be omitted, which is what happens here. In the case of `customStep`, you passed in `block`.

```
val step = CustomStep(block)
```

`block` is this bit from `main`:

```
{
    name = "flang"
    anotherCommand = "derp"
    command = "1111"
}
```

Your alternative of `CustomStep().apply(block)` is the same too. Calling the secondary constructor that you declared will first call the parameterless primary constructor, as you have declared as `: this()`, [and is required](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html#secondary-constructors). This is the same as `CustomStep()`. Then both versions call `block` on `this`.

Comment: oh right. The `this` is implicit. So it's basically `this.init()`, where `init()` just had a bunch of setters in it. Neat!